# Referencing Non-Active Workbook Using Macro in Personal Workbook

Tags: excel, vba

I have a macro that works in any Excel workbook but doesn't work once I place it in my PERSONAL.XLSB file. My goal is to take the tabs from all of the files in a folder on my desktop and copy them into the active file. I know the issue is that I am using This.Workbook as the location reference for the copied tabs but I don't know how else to reference the workbook I am trying to copy the tabs into. I don't want to reference a filepath for where to copy the tabs since this will be used by multiple people in multiple files. Any thoughts would be greatly appreciated.

```
Sub CombineWorkbooks()

Dim Path As Variant
Path = GetFolder(1) & "\"

Dim FileName As String
FileName = Dir(Path & "*.xl??")

Dim ws As Worksheet

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False

Do While FileName <> ""
    Workbooks.Open Path & FileName
    For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets
        ws.Copy after:=ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Count)
    Next ws
    Workbooks(FileName).Close
    FileName = Dir()
Loop

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.DisplayAlerts = True

Exit Sub

End Sub
```

Comment: I think I have your issues solved. Ignore my first post. If it works, please do me a favor of clicking accept (sorry to ask but new people often forget). If it doesn't work, could you clarify when/where you're running this from?

Comment: Thank you for the help! It's odd, the macro is no just opening the first workbook in the identified folder. Once that file is open nothing else happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you define the file to a variable or activeworkbook it should work.

UPDATED as I think I slightly misunderstood the overall objective of macro but the concept is still the same. Let me know if this doesn't work.

```
Sub CombineWorkbooks()

Dim Path As Variant
Path = GetFolder(1) & "\"

Dim FileName As String
FileName = Dir(Path & "*.xl??")

Dim ws As Worksheet, wkBkToCopyTo As Workbook

Set wkBkToCopyTo = ActiveWorkbook 'assuming that you run this with the destination open.



Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False

Do While FileName <> ""
    Workbooks.Open Path & FileName
    For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets
        ws.Copy after:=wkBkToCopyTo.Worksheets(wkBkToCopyTo.Worksheets.Count)
    Next ws
    Workbooks(FileName).Close
    FileName = Dir()
Loop

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.DisplayAlerts = True

Exit Sub

End Sub
```

You could also try to find it based on its name:

```
'you could also use a loop to find it
For Each wkBkToCopyTo In Application.Workbooks
    If InStr(1, wkBkToCopyTo.Name, "someNameof the workbook", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
        Exit For
    End If
Next wkBkToCopyTo
```